# How to convert 2 phase power supply to 3 phase power supply using a Transformer (like Scott transformer)?

Tags: transformer

I'm looking to develop a circuit to convert 2 phase power supply to 3 phase power supply.

My circuit follows: 
[image: circuit diagram]
Input: 
2 phase 400V - phase angle 120degree

Expected output:
3 phase with phase to phase voltage as 440V - 440V - 440V

But
Actual output:
610V - 440V - 150V

There is some problem with phase angle conversion.. 
Help me fix this.

Comment: If you only have 2 wire input as drawn, where are you  seeing 120 degrees with respect to what?

Comment: Practically speaking, the way to power 3-phase equipment from a 2-wire supply is to use a VFD derated for the extra load on the input rectifiers.  The old way was typically to use a rotary phase converter - basically a big idler motor started with a shift capacitor and running as both a motor and generator.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know the Scott-T transformer converts 2-phase to 3-phase. Your sketch shows that you only have one phase as input.

[image]

*Figure 1. The Scott-T when used as a 2-phase to 3-phase converter requires two input phases at 90° to each other. Image source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott-T_transformer).*

There is more on the subject in the linked article.

[image: schematic]

*Figure 2. With your single-phase connection and rated ratios you could expect voltage readings as shown.*

These are not too dissimilar to what you measured.

---

Note that when you have only two-wires on an AC supply that you have only a single phase supply - even if those two wires come off two of the phases on a three-phase supply. This should be clear if you consider that the voltage waveform between the two terminals is a single sinewave. For a poly-phase supply you need to have > 1 sinewave with a phase difference between them.

If you lose one phase on a 3-phase motor the motor the motor (usually) will not start as there is no rotational field. The motor in this condition is "single phase" even though it is connected to two phases of the supply.